# How to reinstall newest Linux Kernel?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

Hello I upgraded all packages on my Ubuntu, and kernel also. But in upgrading process kernel upgrade failed, and I must always after grub load select older kernel. It is a terminal command to reinstall latest kernel?

Answer (score 32):

Run the following command in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image-.*-generic
```

Look for the kernel version you want to reinstall then run:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.X.Y-ZZ-generic
```

<sub>Of course, you must type the actual kernel version (e.g. linux-image-3.8.0-21-generic) instead of linux-image-3.X.Y-ZZ-generic.</sub>

Comment: this works for me

Comment: Or as one-liner `dpkg -l | grep linux-image-.*-generic | sort -k3 | tail -n1 | awk '{system ("sudo apt-get install --reinstall " $2)}'`

Comment: Thank god! This just fixed a networking problem I could not figure out!

Comment: Since there is also a package called `linux-image-generic` 9with no version number), should I do something with that, too?