# No soundcard detected after reinstalling audio drivers

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

So I've followed [this guide](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-install-oss4-in-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-for-better-sound-quality.html) to install the OSS4 sound drivers, but after installing it (second terminal command in the guide), it failed loading it, and I was left with no sound. I reinstalled `linux-sound-base` and switched back to ALSA, restarted the computer with no success. I then removed `alsa-base`, `pulseaudio` and `linux-sound-base` altogether, and re-installed them. It broke my System Settings, but I was able to repair the damage using `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Output for `aplay -l` is: `aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...`

When I open the Sound section in System Settings, the only output device listed is "Dummy Output", and none are listed under the "Input" tab.

I'd like to know what my options are, aside from reinstalling the entire operating system. Thanks in advance!

Comment: OSS4 removes the ALSA kernel drivers. You probably need to reinstall the kernel.

Comment: Yes, as Alsa drivers now comes with the linux kernel , you can first try to run a normal software update:  
it will hopefully works, except if your are already at last kernel version.

Comment: [Reinstalling the kernel](http://askubuntu.com/questions/298853/how-to-reinstall-newest-linux-kernel) didn't help either

Comment: added as answer: also reinstall linux-image-extra (contains alsa drivers)

Answer (score 1):

I've carefully read the linked instructions and I cannot help but notice that down at the bottom it lists instructions for reversing its changes.  Your post doesn't appear to indicate you did that reversing.

I submit that it would be helpful to you to either uninstall those packages installed using those linked instructions, or at the very least, determine if they are still installed.

I'm no expert at this, but if you like doing stuff with command lines, you might try this one to see which OSS4 packages may still be installed.

dpkg -l | grep -i oss4

Otherwise I'd advise, as I so frequently advise, installing the Synaptic Package Manager, and either using its HISTORY (located under the file menu), or a search, to see which oss4 packages are currently installed on your system, and mark them for removal.  Considering how easy Synaptic makes this operation, I'm surprised it isn't mentioned more often.

In the end, you may still need to reinstall your entire system, but I'm sure that if you are ever going to succeed in the configuration of your recalcitrant sound device, you are first going to have to overcome its driver issues.

Comment: I did what the guide said, unfortunately I still only see the "Dummy Audio" device listed. The history in Synaptic Package Manager is empty, and no OSS4 packages are installed.

Comment: I don't know if I should be telling you this, but I know what I'd do if this happened to me.  If only to satisfy my curiousity, I'd plug in an external USB sound adapter, of the typical $5-10 variety.  I find them handy sometimes.  It would be helpful to know if your system is capable of recognizing sound hardware.

Answer (score 0):

As Alsa drivers now comes with the linux kernel , you can first try to run a normal software update:
it will hopefully works except if your are already at last kernel version.

In this case, try to force a kernel reinstall  successively copying and running this 4 commands in a terminal :

```
sudo apt-get clean -qq    
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-`uname -r` 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-extra-`uname -r`
```

Then reboot

Comment: I've tried running those commands, no luck. Running `sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra` outputs `E: Unable to locate package linux-image-extra`

Comment: you must add the -`uname -r` at the end (with backquotes as indicated)

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. I've installed the broken `oss4-dkms` package, and some packages throw an error when attempting to install them, something like: `Cannot install, you've held broken packages`. I think the only way for me to get the sound working at this point would be to successfully install OSS4.