# 14.04 Latest 3.19 Kernel causes Kernel Panick (3.19.0-49-generic)

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel

Let me start by stating that this post is extremely similar to [this other post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471012/ubuntu-14-04-lts-fails-to-start-with-a-kernel-panic) that was made a year ago but its the specifics that have changed and **I want to double check if I should file a bug report, or if there is something else I should do first to try and fix my kernel installation**.

I've updated my computer and when I boot the latest kernel I am greeted by a purple screen. When I try to run recovery mode in that kernel, I am greeted by a kernel panic output.

I tried re-installing the latest 3.19 kernel by using [the advice given here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298853/how-to-reinstall-newest-linux-kernel). The output of which is below (in case there is any useful information).

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.19.0-49-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libx265-59
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/16.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Can't exec "locale": Permission denied at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
(Reading database ... 1029059 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.19.0-49-generic_3.19.0-49.55~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Can't exec "locale": Permission denied at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.19.0-49-generic (3.19.0-49.55~14.04.1) over (3.19.0-49.55~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-extlinux 3.19.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic
P: Checking for EXTLINUX directory... found.
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-47-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-60-generic.efi.signed...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-60-generic...
  No volume groups found
P: Installing debian theme... done.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic
Setting up linux-image-3.19.0-49-generic (3.19.0-49.55~14.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Not updating initrd symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(3.19.0-49.55~14.04.1 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Not updating image symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(3.19.0-49.55~14.04.1 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-49-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.19.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.19.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-extlinux 3.19.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic
P: Checking for EXTLINUX directory... found.
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-47-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-60-generic.efi.signed...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-60-generic...
  No volume groups found
P: Installing debian theme... done.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-49-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-47-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-60-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-60-generic
  No volume groups found
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

For now I can just keep booting off the old kernel, but I am tempted to upgrade to 4.2 by executing:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends \
linux-generic-lts-wily
```

This has worked on a desktop I was re-setting up anyway and I wanted to see if it would work. It's interesting that [the HWE docs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) state that this is okay for the server and doesn't mention it for the desktop which is why I've been holding off.

---

## Update 11 Feb 2016

I tried installing the 4.2 kernel and got the same issue, so I don't think it's something to do with the kernel. I would love some advice on diagnosing this issue. Otherwise it looks like I need to perform a full reinstallation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel panics in Ubuntu's official kernels should almost always be reported to the [kernel bug tracker on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux), where they may be escalated to upstream bug trackers if necessary – unless of course you find a similar existing report.

I believe this holds true in your case.

Comment: Great thanks for your help. I have added the bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1545257).

Comment: I did, its buried in there with "My original post is at..." and links here.