# Black screen at normal boot; login loop at terminal boot - after upgrading 20.04 to 22.04:

Tags: boot, nvidia, upgrade, login, 22.04

After upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS, my workstation (which has a Nvidia RTX 3080 12gb installed) ceased being able to boot. Regular boot attempts results in the well known [black screen with blinking and non-responsive curso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297080/ubuntu-boots-to-a-black-screen-with-blinking-a-underscore-character-after-releas)r.

However, in my case, if I drop to terminal mode, e.g. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login attempts with any user name/password registered in the system leads to a terminal login loop (not [desktop login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)) - that is, after correct user name and password are inserted, it just goes back to the login terminal prompt.

The only exception is if I log with user "root" and the root password at the terminal login prompt - that works and leads to a regular terminal session (same works at recovery mode).

**What have I tried:**

- the usual `nomodeset` and `no splash` parameters for logging in ([see](https://askubuntu.com/a/162076));
- the usual `sudo apt-get update` + `sudo apt-get upgrade` + `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` ([see](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1620479));
- reinstalling Nvidia most recent drivers via root terminal ([see](https://askubuntu.com/a/650253));
- turning off Wayland ([see](https://askubuntu.com/a/1286728));
- turning on and reconfiguring lightdm (`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`) ([see](https://askubuntu.com/a/883399/1665637));
- tried gdm3 instead of lightdm ([see](https://askubuntu.com/a/350858));
- checking `.Xauthority` ([see](https://askubuntu.com/a/223634));
- checking if my disk is full ([see](https://askubuntu.com/a/710192));
- reinstalling the desktop environment ([see](https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-ubuntu-login-loop-issue/));
- reinstalling the kernel ([see](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298853/how-to-reinstall-newest-linux-kernel));

My question: what else can be done to try to solve this problem? My impression is that the key is to, first, understand what it causing the login-loop at terminal mode - but I have found very scarce mentions online to login-loop issues at terminal mode (desktop login-loop issues are somewhat common).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an insanely time consuming journey, I found out that the login loop at terminal was being caused by some permission issues - which I never altered myself. Anyway, the solution was to reestablish the following:

```
chmod 755 /
chmod 755 /bin
chmod 755 /lib
chmod 755 /lib64
```

With that, I was able to login via terminal with any user, at tty.

Then, the black screen with flashing cursor was treated with an install of the very recent Kernel 5.15.58:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-5.15.0-58-generic
```

And a purge + reinstall of the most recent Nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```